# Installing Tensorflow with GPU support fails without any error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tensorflow, installation, gpu

This is how i configured the  installation of Tensorflow -> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljv4a.png)
, at the end cuda libraries are not setting up.

I have Installed Cuda 8.0, cuDNN 5.1.10 and i have Nvidia GForce 1060 graphics card.Can anyone tell me the solution for this. Thanks in advance.

I am new to stackoverflow, if any mistakes kindly apologise me.

Comment: I am not sure but is there a way to build TF via cmake? Via cmake, you can see a list of what all libraries are being utilised to build the binaries.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Anyway, I've written a small guide here: http://queirozf.com/entries/installing-cuda-tk-and-tensorflow-on-a-clean-ubuntu-16-04-install

Comment: Would you please add the error ? or what's failing ?

Comment: If tensor flow is installed with gpu support it will show like "setting up cuda"  before completion. But in my case it's not showing by this I can say it's failing to install tensor flow with gpu support @ hars

Comment: I'll go though the guide once @Felipe Almeida